# NSNumberFormatter changes 0.5 to .50

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter, eureka-forms

My tension is from Eureka (https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) with the usage of a NSFormatter.

My application changes a `0,75` to 0 on the first try and `1,75` to `1.00`

After this, I tried multiples things like

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
```

or with `formatter.numberStyle = .decimal`

I don't know how I can tell :

*"Okay, now `1,75` equals `1.75`and `0,75` equals `0.75`"*

My Decimal row with Eureka :

```
        timeField = DecimalRow(){ row in
           row.title = "Duration"
           row.placeholder = "1.25"
           row.value = timesheet.time
        }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you converting string -> number or number -> string?

Comment: @dan Number -> String

Comment: How did you try `transform`? No code?

Comment: @Ryan I have limited action on Eureka for this, they let use a NSFormatter instance for this case

Comment: Need more details to answer your question. Unless you provide the code how you transform `0.75` to `0`, no way to answer it.

Comment: @Ryan have a look, Like I said, It's not from my code but from Eureka with their updates :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable problem is that you are not setting locale on the formatter and you are not setting decimal separator either. I would assume the decimal separator will be `.`, too.

Therefore `0,75` gets parsed as `0` because the `,` character is unknown.

The following should fix your problem:

```
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
```

Answer (score 1):

## Approach:

- Don't hard code the formatting separator.
- Set the locale or get the current locale and set it.

## Code:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.locale = Locale.current //or formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GR")

let n1 = NSNumber(value: 0.75)
formatter.string(from: n1)
```

## Getting all Locale identifiers:

```
Locale.availableIdentifiers
```

Comment: You need to add `minimumIntegerDigits = 1` with this :-)

Comment: You wanted to 2 decimal digits based on your example right ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the nice guy, who deleted his comment.

He is right, the solution was `formatter.decimalSeparator = ","` instead of grouping separator, thanks you so mutch !

Plus, for this, you need to use `row.useFormatterOnDidBeginEditing = true`, with this, the `,`don't turn into `.` !

Thanks for all !

Comment: I have undeleted my answer, I wanted to inspect the library more because I wasn't really sure how it parses the numbers. However, setting the locale explicitly is usually the better idea. The probably reason is that the default parsing is one using their own [DecimalFormatter](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/0791f202fad47e68ffe9453f313e42673c6eb36b/Source/Rows/Common/DecimalFormatter.swift) which does not really work correctly with grouping separators.